# when I "run" it gives an error in Flutter. Photo attached

Tags: flutter

When I "run" it gives an error in Flutter:
[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuerty.of(context).size.height - 85,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(35),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(35),
              )
          ),
          child: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        children: <Widget>[

              Container(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(
                'Освежающие напитки',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              subtitle: Text(
                  'Больше 100 видов напитков',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
              ),
              trailing: Icon(Icons.panorama_horizontal),
            ),
          ),

          Container(
            child: Text("Горизонтальный список карточек"),
          ),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
              child: Text("Каталог коктейлей"),
        ),

        Container(
        child: Text("Список каталогов"),
        ),

        ],
      ),
    ),
    ),
      // !-БОТТОМ БАР
    );
  }
  }

class MediaQuerty {
  static of(BuildContext context) {}
}`enter code here`
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

everything is fine you just need to change MediaQuerty to MediaQuery

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.amberAccent,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 85,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: Colors.white,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(35),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(35),
              )),
          child: ListView(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'Освежающие напитки',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    'Больше 100 видов напитков',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                  ),
                  trailing: Icon(Icons.panorama_horizontal),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text("Горизонтальный список карточек"),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Text("Каталог коктейлей"),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Text("Список каталогов"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      // !-БОТТОМ БАР
    );
  }
}
```

replace your HomePage class with this